# Combining two IF functions in one cell using Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have these two IF functions that work correctly on their own. I need to combine the two into one cell but can't seem to get them to work. Any help would be appreciated. And thanks in advance.

Screen capture 1
[image]

```
=IF(AND((D5="Intel"),(Z5="Not Attempted")),"Not Attempted")
```

Screen capture 2
[image]

`=IF(AND(OR(D5="Pilot", D5="Sensor", D5="Admin"),(Z5="Not Attempted"),OR(C5="E-1",C5="E-2",C5="E-3",C5="E-7",C5="E-8",C5="E-9",C5="O-4",C5="O-5",C5="O-6")),"Not Required", "Not Attempted"`)

I've tried the following combos without any luck.

This one results in screen capture 3
[image]

```
=IF(AND((D5="Intel"),(Z5="Not Attempted")),"Not Attempted")=IF(AND(OR(D5="Pilot", D5="Sensor", D5="Admin"),(Z5="Not Attempted"),OR(C5="E-1",C5="E-2",C5="E-3",C5="E-7",C5="E-8",C5="E-9",C5="O-4",C5="O-5",C5="O-6")),"Not Required", "Not Attempted")
```

This combo results in a #VALUE! Error in the cell:

```
=IF(AND((D5="Intel"),(Z5="Not Attempted")),"Not Attempted"),IF(AND(OR(D5="Pilot", D5="Sensor", D5="Admin"),(Z5="Not Attempted"),OR(C5="E-1",C5="E-2",C5="E-3",C5="E-7",C5="E-8",C5="E-9",C5="O-4",C5="O-5",C5="O-6")),"Not Required", "Not Attempted")
```

And this screen capture is me manually updating the cells to show what I need them to show, screen capture 4

[image]

Comment: http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b43/bakdawg/Capture1_zps5446303f.png

Comment: http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b43/bakdawg/Capture2_zps7a9fcc8d.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are really long `IF` if you ask me!

But if I understand what you're trying to do...

It will be either this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(D5="Pilot", D5="Sensor", D5="Admin"),(Z5="Not Attempted"),OR(C5="E-1",C5="E-2",C5="E-3",C5="E-7",C5="E-8",C5="E-9",C5="O-4",C5="O-5",C5="O-6")),"Not Required", IF(AND((D5="Intel"),(Z5="Not Attempted")),"Not Attempted"))
```

Or this:

```
=IF(AND((D5="Intel"),(Z5="Not Attempted")),"Not Attempted", IF(AND(OR(D5="Pilot", D5="Sensor", D5="Admin"),(Z5="Not Attempted"),OR(C5="E-1",C5="E-2",C5="E-3",C5="E-7",C5="E-8",C5="E-9",C5="O-4",C5="O-5",C5="O-6")),"Not Required", "Not Attempted"))
```

It depends on what you want to check for first.

---

EDIT: After reconsidering the formula, maybe this would be better:

```
=IF(AND(OR(D5="Pilot", D5="Sensor", D5="Admin"),(Z5="Not Attempted"),OR(C5="E-1",C5="E-2",C5="E-3",C5="E-7",C5="E-8",C5="E-9",C5="O-4",C5="O-5",C5="O-6")),"Not Required", IF(Z5="Not Attempted","Not Attempted"))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! Haha yes they are really long but it's what I have to work with...The first one you posted is VERY close and the second one has a few correct. But on the first one if you see on my screen shot I highlighted in yellow should show "Not Attempted" as they are an O-1 Pilot who is not exempt in the rule in the formula and have not completed it in column Z.   http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b43/bakdawg/Capture7_zpsba4c9714.png

Comment: @Bryce Oh that makes much more sense now! I admit it didn't make much sense initially haha ^^; Okay, logically, every person who is not exempt and has "Not attempted" should get "Not attempted", right? Currently, the formula only checks for `Intel` for this particular category. The formula can be made shorter by checking all personnel, not just `Intel` by removing the AND in the second formula. I added that formula in my answer. See if this works now! ^^

Comment: To help clarifiy what I'm trying to accomplish.

If their position is Intel they have to have a date in column Z which should show False in column U. If column Z shows not completed then column U needs to show Not Completed

Comment: The other positions (pilot, sensor, admin) need to show a date in column Z which again should show false in column U. There are several ranks that are exempt (all those shown in the formula) and they should show not required if they have a Not Completed in their respective column Z. And if they aren't exempt based off of rank and have a Not Completed in column Z then column U should also show Not Completed

Comment: Jerry - I think that works!!! I will try to check it against my entire document but so far it looks good. Thank you so much for the help!

-Bryce

Comment: @Bryce Okay, let me know if there are any naughty records not wanting to follow the formula and I'll try come up with a strict-er formula ;)